# how do i solve does not "opens javax.management" to unnamed module

Tags: java

I'm running some junit test in my old setup without problems. I have upgraded java to java 17. Now when I run the test i receive a lot of similar messages like the title says.

Until now I've been able to solve it by adding the following to maven surefire plugin:

```
          <argLine>
            --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED
----->      --add-opens java.management/javax.management.openmbean=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED
          </argLine>
```

despite having added openmbean to this list it does not solve the problem. What do I need to write in the argLine to remove the

does not "opens javax.management" to unnamed module

error message?

Kim

Comment: The error mentions the `javax.management` package, yet you're opening the `javax.management.openmbean` package. If you need both, then add another argument for the former, otherwise replace the argument for the latter with one for the former.